# My selected date is showing one day before in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have used a native datepicker for that and I am converting the date to `toISOString()` but the problem is that it is showing one day before.

This is my ts:

```
this.datePicker.show({
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date',
  androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
}).then(
  date => {
    me.acceptchallengeform.setValue({
      startchallenge: new Date(date).toISOString().split('T')[0], 
    });
    console.log('Got date: ', date)},
  err => {
    console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)}
);
```

var DatePickerDate ='Thu Aug 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)';

var myDate = new Date(DatePickerDate).toISOString().split('T')[0];

so myDate is now 2018-08-08

The problem is that it is showing the date one day before.

But I want to show the exact selected date.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*new Date()* return the date using your system timezone.

*toISOString()* return the date in UTC and the time part of your date is midnight, so it returns Thu Aug 08 2018 23:00:00 *(BST - 1h)*, that's why you're getting one day before.

What are your trying to do exactly?

> Editing my answer following comment

- in your case I would choose the easy way as you apparently don't need any timezone information:

  startchallenge: date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();

  - or you can use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: I  am trying to get the exact selected date but I am getting one day before.So, Can you please help me in this?

Comment: date.getMonth() should be date.getMonth() + 1

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
me.acceptchallengeform.setValue({
   startchallenge: new Date(date).toISOString().split('T')[0], 
});
```

This will solve your problem.